# inverse table with css and scroll

Tags: html, css

```css
.box{
 position: relative;
 display: box;
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: grey;
}

table.market{
 position: relative;
 display: box;
 width: 100%;
}

.market tbody tr {
 color: #555;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #1f2943;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 100%;
}

.market tbody tr:hover {
 color: #555;
 background-color: #192b2f;
}

.market tbody{
 height: 200px;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column-reverse;
 flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<table class="market" border="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>6,53,500</td>
   <td>0.28368756</td>
   <td>74125.05</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td>5,53,500</td>
   <td>0.28368756</td>
   <td>74125.05</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td>5,53,500</td>
   <td>0.28368756</td>
   <td>74125.05</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td>5,53,500</td>
   <td>0.28368756</td>
   <td>74125.05</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td>5,53,500</td>
   <td>0.28368756</td>
   <td>74125.05</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td>5,53,500</td>
   <td>0.28368756</td>
   <td>74125.05</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td>5,53,500</td>
   <td>0.28368756</td>
   <td>74125.05</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td>5,53,500</td>
   <td>0.28368756</td>
   <td>74125.05</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td>5,53,500</td>
   <td>0.28368756</td>
   <td>74125.05</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Working fine but i need colum with 100% auto adjust with same size and Reverse Scroll. Reverse and scroll fine but problem is width **td** is not equal and width 100% not working.

I am working on Custom Exchange and this is sale Order Table part and need reverse table from high price to low Price.

Low Price will be start from Bottom.

Please solve my problems 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the tds need to be equally split across the whole table you can make each row (ie the tr) a flex element and set the tds to fill the available space by using:

```
td {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-basis: 0;
   padding:2px;
}
```

As for sorting the data you have in your table, your code will reverse the order its outputted but it might make sense to sort this server side when generating the HTML for the table rather than relying on a CSS solution.

Amended Snippet

```css
.market tbody tr {    
    color: #555;    
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1f2943;    
    cursor: pointer;    
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
}

td {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    padding:2px;
}
```